Workers Comp. Insurance with Regard to Single-Member LLCs in Virginia
Consider that I own a single-member LLC in Virginia.
Must I carry Workers Comp. insurance (in the U.S.) because I pay my wife from time to time?
I ask, because I am under the impression that if a business entity has two or more "employees," it needs to carry the said insurance.
Is there a way to legally avoid paying for Workers Comp. in this situation?

Workers compensation insurance is a matter of state law (or admiralty law in the case of maritime ventures). On this particular issue, state law varies considerably from state to state.

Is the LLC owner even considered to be an employee for the purpose of workers comp?

The requirement is for "more than two", not "two or more".
From Virginia Workers' Compensation Commission:

As a general rule, a business with more than two employees is required to carry workers’ compensation coverage. An employee is viewed broadly under workers’ compensation law and includes part-time, seasonal and temporary workers, minors, trainees, immigrants and working family members.

If she's your only employee, then you have two employees, so you don't need to carry coverage.

They may have 1 employee. Tax-wise, the owner of a single-member LLC cannot be an employee. You have to study the workers comp regulations to see if this applies there as well.

The FAQ includes "Executive officers also count as employees." Isn't the owner an executive officer?

And FAQ#13 addresses LLC members. If they perform work and receive pay, they're considered employees for the purpose of worker's comp.

The very first sentence of FAQ #13 seems to state the opposite of what you claim. "Under Virginia law, a limited liability company (LLC) is identified as an employee [should read employer?] and a member of a LLC having only one member is not covered under the Act unless they specifically notify the insurer of their election to be covered." A single-member LLC is a special case.
